# Something weird in Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have some class with private member _stuffs which is of type IStuffs an interface.

When I set a break point just before getting out of the constructor, when debugging and watching the variable at the break point, local variable _stuffs is not null (filled with MyStuffs Object) whereas this._stuffs is null and when back in caller instance MyModelApp._stuffs stays null. Why it is not set with MyStuffs Object ?

```
public class MyModelApp : ModelApp, IModelApp
{

   private App _parent;

   private IStuffs _stuffs;

   public MyModelApp(object parent)
      : base(parent)
   {
      IStuffs _stuffs = new MyStuffs(this);

      // Break point here
   }    
}
```

Comment: I wonder how this compiles ...

Comment: @FrederikGheysels What's wrong with this?

Comment: Why would you expect the `_stuffs` fields to be non-null if you did not assigned any value to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you realize you're actually assigning to local variable and not to instance variable?

```
private IStuffs _stuffs;

public MyModelApp(object parent)
: base(parent)
{
    IStuffs _stuffs = new MyStuffs(this);//This is a local variable

    //If you need local variable also here, just rename it
    //or use this qualifier

    this._stuffs = new MyStuffs(this);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `_` prefix for local variables, that's why you get the confusion. Maintain a distinction in naming convention.

Comment: I didn't intend to create a local variable I did redeclare the type without really willing it so the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Look carefully at your constructor:

```
public MyModelApp(object parent)
   : base(parent)
{
   IStuffs _stuffs = new MyStuffs(this);
}
```

You're declaring a *local variable* called `_stuffs` and giving it a value. That is *not* the same as the field `_stuffs`. I strongly suspect that you don't want a local variable - you just want to initialize the field instead:

```
public MyModelApp(object parent)
   : base(parent)
{
   _stuffs = new MyStuffs(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating `_stuffs` as a new *local variable*, and not as the `private IStuffs _stuffs`, which has *global* scope. I assume you mean to assign `new MyStuffs(this);` to the global field `_stuffs` instead of creating an entire new object, because currently you have **two different variables**, but you are getting confused becaus they have the same name.

```
private IStuffs _stuffs;

public MyModelApp(object parent)
  : base(parent)
{
   _stuffs = new MyStuffs(this);
}
```

The above is the correct way, creating a new `MyStuffs` object as the variable in the global scope rather than the local scope.